# Prove or disprove set is an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a Euclidean domain with Euclidean function $\delta$. Prove or disprove the following: 
$$A=\{a \in R \mid \delta(a) > \delta(1) \} \cup  \{ 0 \}$$
is an ideal of $R$.

If I take $R=\mathbb{Z} [x]$, the ring of polynomials with integer coefficients, then this is a Euclidean ring with $\delta(f)=deg(f)$.
Then for $f=x+1$ and $g=-x$, we have $\deg(f)=deg(g)=1$, so $f,g \in A$.
But $f+g=x+1-x=1$, so $deg(f+g)=deg(1)=0$, so $f+g \notin A$.
I think this shows that $A$ is not a subring of $R$, so it is not an ideal of $R$ either. Is my thinking correct?

Comment: $(\mathbb{Z}[X],deg)$ is not a Euclidean ring, there are no polynomials with integer coefficients $Q$ and $R$ satisfying $X=2XQ+R$ and $deg(R)<1$.

Comment: What if I take $\mathbb{Z}_7 [x]$ instead? I know that $\mathbb{Z}_7$ is a field.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_7$ is a field so yes $(\mathbb{Z}_7[x],deg)$ is a Euclidean ring.